# EXTRACT function position in long query

Tags: sql, oracle, extract

I would like to ask for some expertise on the below please. I am quite new to SQL, so please forgive any mistakes or incorrectness. I have written the below SQL which works as I need with now issues:

```sql
SELECT a.TICKET,
       f.CODE,
       f.SEQUENCE,
       f.CLEARSEQUENCE,
       f.TOTALMINUTES,
       a.SEV,
       a.ORIGSEV,
       a.CUSTOMER,
       a.WORKGROUP,
       a.NOC,
       d.COUNTRYA,
       d.COUNTRYZ,
       a.IDENTIFIER,
       f.ORIGDTTM,
FROM   SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVHEADER a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVCUSTOMER d ON a.TICKET=d.TICKET 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVCODEDATA f ON a.TICKET=f.TICKET
WHERE  a.CLOSEDDT >= to_timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND    a.WORKGROUP IN ('SVCDSK.DES-INTL')
AND    a.SEV in (1,2,3,4)
AND    d.COUNTRYA IN ('CHN','JPN','HKG','GUM','IDN','PRK','KOR','MYS','MMR','NZL','PHL','SGP','TWN','THA','VNM')
```

I now need to extract `HOUR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `DAY OF WEEK` from the `f.ORIGDTTM` field. I have managed to get this working as below using just the basic query:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM ORIGDTTM) "HOUR",
       EXTRACT(month FROM ORIGDTTM) "MONTH"
FROM   ETMSACTV.T3TKTNADDATA;
```

My problem is how can I add the `EXTRACT` functions into the long, complex query. I have tried to place it within a number of places with no results.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, the ORIGDTTM field is within the SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVCODEDATA table

Comment: " have tried to place it within a number of places with no results." Please, elaborate more on this statement: what the error you get and what is the query you've tried?

Comment: Hi astentx - I added the function exactly per the answers to my question. Error message I am getting : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 00923. 00000 - "FROM keyword not found where expected" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 46 Column: 1

Comment: @JohnWilliams - did you just forget to add a comma - either after th4e last existing column expression (if adding at the end of the select list) or after your last new clause (if adding in the middle)? (The code you posted already has a trailing comma - which will throw ORA-00936: missing expression, so that doesn't work as you need now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them to a long query, just as you'd add them to a short one.

```
SELECT a.ticket,
       f.code,
       f.sequence,
       f.clearsequence,
       f.totalminutes,
       a.sev,
       a.origsev,
       a.customer,
       a.workgroup,
       a.noc,
       d.countrya,
       d.countryz,
       a.identifier,
       f.origdttm,
       --
       EXTRACT (HOUR FROM f.origdttm) "HOUR",         --> here
       EXTRACT (MONTH FROM f.origdttm) "MONTH"        --> here
  FROM systemactv.t3sevheader a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN systemactv.t3sevcustomer d ON a.ticket = d.ticket
       LEFT OUTER JOIN systemactv.t3sevcodedata f ON a.ticket = f.ticket
 WHERE     a.closeddt >=
           TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       AND a.workgroup IN ('SVCDSK.DES-INTL')
       AND a.sev IN (1,
                     2,
                     3,
                     4)
       AND d.countrya IN ('CHN',
                          'JPN',
                          'HKG',
                          'GUM',
                          'IDN',
                          'PRK',
                          'KOR',
                          'MYS',
                          'MMR',
                          'NZL',
                          'PHL',
                          'SGP',
                          'TWN',
                          'THA',
                          'VNM')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add them to the query:

```sql
SELECT a.TICKET,
       f.CODE,
       f.SEQUENCE,
       f.CLEARSEQUENCE,
       f.TOTALMINUTES,
       a.SEV,
       a.ORIGSEV,
       a.CUSTOMER,
       a.WORKGROUP,
       a.NOC,
       d.COUNTRYA,
       d.COUNTRYZ,
       a.IDENTIFIER,
       f.ORIGDTTM,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM f.ORIGDTTM) AS month,
       EXTRACT(DAY   FROM f.ORIGDTTM) AS day,
       EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM f.ORIGDTTM) AS hour,
       TRUNC(f.ORIGDTTM) - TRUNC(f.ORIGDTTM, 'IW') AS day_of_week,
         -- monday = 0, ..., sunday = 6
       TO_CHAR(f.ORIGDTTM, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS day_of_week_alt
FROM   SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVHEADER a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVCUSTOMER d ON a.TICKET=d.TICKET 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSTEMACTV.T3SEVCODEDATA f ON a.TICKET=f.TICKET
WHERE  a.CLOSEDDT >= TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
AND    a.WORKGROUP IN ('SVCDSK.DES-INTL')
AND    a.SEV in (1,2,3,4)
AND    d.COUNTRYA IN ('CHN','JPN','HKG','GUM','IDN','PRK','KOR','MYS','MMR','NZL','PHL','SGP','TWN','THA','VNM')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0888804495ac4cd85b78f9f8e84c243)*

Comment: Thank you both, I have tried both options but I continue to get the error:                       
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 1    any idea? the query works fine with the EXTRACT functions

Comment: @JohnWilliams It works fine for me; see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0888804495ac4cd85b78f9f8e84c243). Also, the query does not have 46 lines.

Comment: thank you @MTO, rookie mistake, I had an extra line in there, too much screen time today.